# The Pin Test - Urban Legend or Fact?

Tags: talmud-gemara, memory

I have heard that certain, erudite Gedolim had photographic memories and passed the pin test. A volume of Talmud would be opened; a pin was thrust through its pages. The Gadol would look at the word/letter that the pin first entered into and then recite the other letters/words it hit on other pages too. Is there any source for this?

The most conservative approach to this test is that it was performed for a single daf/double sided page of Talmud. The Gadol would see which word was pierced on the revealed Amud Aleph - A side - and then reveal which word was hit on the hidden Amud Beit - B side. Any sources?

Comment: I have heard of so many people who supposedly did it. All I will point out that until recently the print was usually not consistently centered on the page, which would make this all the more difficult with a personal gemara, and at least to me , seemingly not plausible with a random gemara that the individual was not accustomed to.

Comment: Seems crazy anyone would be poking a Seffer like that, major bizayon vibes. But especially since these stories are about gedolim two hundred years ago when sefarim were allot more expensive.

Answer (score 1):

It’s quoted as having happened [here](https://psycnet.apa.org/doiLanding?doi=10.1037%2Fh0070091) in a peer-reviewed journal.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shas_Pollak

Comment: https://forum.artofmemory.com/t/shas-pollak-memorization-feat-or-magic-trick/37765